# Drawing Adjustable Rectangles

Tags: dynamic

I am currently working on a project that requires a user interface. I need to have an interface on this website that allows a user to dynamically adjust a rectangular shape that displays this adjustment to them on the website in real time. Does anyone have any suggestions for coding languages that would be optimal for this?

Pretty much I need a way to display to the user a rectangle that they can drag and drop the lengths of on the screen as they desire. Very similar to the MS Word shape drawing tools where the user can pick the edge of and expand or collapse.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **JavaScript** using **jQuery** Library.

There is an UI element called [`resizable`](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#default) in jQuery that give the same effect you want:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

**Alternatively**, you could write one from scratch using pure **JavaScript**, [here is a good example](https://medium.com/the-z/making-a-resizable-div-in-js-is-not-easy-as-you-think-bda19a1bc53d)

[image]

Comment: @anandpkb did you find my answer useful? How did you end up doing this?